# Dynamically changing images using setInterval

Tags: reactjs, gif

In initially wanted to change the speed of a gif based on a user's input, but that does not seem feasible as the gif's fps is set in the file's header. This would require some low level programming.

My next proposed solution was to import each frame individually and use setInterval to dynamically flip through the frames. Problem with this solution is that the component will not mount in a time based fashion. Some frames will take less or more time to load.

Open to hearing any other suggestions.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import frame0 from '../../assets/splitImages/frame_00_delay-0.08s.jpg';
import frame1 from '../../assets/splitImages/frame_01_delay-0.08s.jpg';
import frame2 from '../../assets/splitImages/frame_02_delay-0.08s.jpg';
import frame3 from '../../assets/splitImages/frame_03_delay-0.08s.jpg';
import frame4 from '../../assets/splitImages/frame_04_delay-0.08s.jpg';
import frame5 from '../../assets/splitImages/frame_05_delay-0.08s.jpg';
import frame6 from '../../assets/splitImages/frame_06_delay-0.08s.jpg';
import frame7 from '../../assets/splitImages/frame_07_delay-0.08s.jpg';
import frame8 from '../../assets/splitImages/frame_08_delay-0.08s.jpg';
import frame9 from '../../assets/splitImages/frame_09_delay-0.08s.jpg';
import frame10 from '../../assets/splitImages/frame_10_delay-0.08s.jpg';
import frame11 from '../../assets/splitImages/frame_11_delay-0.08s.jpg';
import frame12 from '../../assets/splitImages/frame_12_delay-0.08s.jpg';
import frame13 from '../../assets/splitImages/frame_13_delay-0.08s.jpg';
import frame14 from '../../assets/splitImages/frame_14_delay-0.08s.jpg';
import frame15 from '../../assets/splitImages/frame_15_delay-0.08s.jpg';
import frame16 from '../../assets/splitImages/frame_16_delay-0.08s.jpg';
import frame17 from '../../assets/splitImages/frame_17_delay-0.08s.jpg';
import frame18 from '../../assets/splitImages/frame_18_delay-0.08s.jpg';
import frame19 from '../../assets/splitImages/frame_19_delay-0.08s.jpg';

class ImageDisplay extends Component {
  state = {
    imageIndex: 0,
  }

  setImageIndex = () => {
    let { imageIndex } = this.state;
    if (imageIndex === 19) {
      imageIndex = 0;
    } else {
      imageIndex += 1;
    }
    this.setState({ imageIndex });
  }

  render() {
    const imageList = [
      frame0,
      frame1,
      frame2,
      frame3,
      frame4,
      frame5,
      frame6,
      frame7,
      frame8,
      frame9,
      frame10,
      frame11,
      frame12,
      frame13,
      frame14,
      frame15,
      frame16,
      frame17,
      frame18,
      frame19,
    ];
    const { imageIndex } = this.state;

    setInterval(() => {
      this.setImageIndex();
    }, 2000);
    console.log('imageIndex ', imageIndex);

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <img src={imageList[imageIndex]} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default ImageDisplay;
```

Comment: Render all of the frames and just use z-index or display none` to show/hide the one you care about. Though have fast do you need it? React rendering is pretty fast, faster than a normal gif speed I would think

Comment: Are there multiple instances of the `ImageDisplay` component ?

Comment: I am not sure if I understood the problem: do you need this component to just continuously loop through the frames every 2 seconds?

Comment: I also feel that here there is a memory leak, because at each render you set an interval and never ever clear it. Not good. Can you answer to my previous comment? I think I can provide a solution.

Comment: suggest to change `setInterval` to `setTimeout` in your code, and better to move it outside of `render`

Comment: Hi @0xc14m1z, apologies for the delay. Yes, in the end, I am looking for the component to loop through the frames. In the code above, I have it set to 2 seconds, but I would actually need something closer to 1/10th of a second for each frame.

The memory leak issue makes a lot of sense. I'm going to setTimeout and see if that resolves the issue. (Thanks @Van)

Answer (score 0):

The following solution seems to work. Timing of the image changes is accurate enough to pass my eye ball test.

The main issue was that I had setInterval in the render() method. Moving to componentWillMount or componentDidMount fixed this issue.

It seems to be re-render the component but does not re-mount it. I assume this is because React is able to determine that only the  element is updated and not the entire component.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import frame0 from '../../assets/splitImages/frame_00_delay-0.08s.jpg';
import frame1 from '../../assets/splitImages/frame_01_delay-0.08s.jpg';
import frame2 from '../../assets/splitImages/frame_02_delay-0.08s.jpg';
import frame3 from '../../assets/splitImages/frame_03_delay-0.08s.jpg';
import frame4 from '../../assets/splitImages/frame_04_delay-0.08s.jpg';
import frame5 from '../../assets/splitImages/frame_05_delay-0.08s.jpg';
import frame6 from '../../assets/splitImages/frame_06_delay-0.08s.jpg';
import frame7 from '../../assets/splitImages/frame_07_delay-0.08s.jpg';
import frame8 from '../../assets/splitImages/frame_08_delay-0.08s.jpg';
import frame9 from '../../assets/splitImages/frame_09_delay-0.08s.jpg';
import frame10 from '../../assets/splitImages/frame_10_delay-0.08s.jpg';
import frame11 from '../../assets/splitImages/frame_11_delay-0.08s.jpg';
import frame12 from '../../assets/splitImages/frame_12_delay-0.08s.jpg';
import frame13 from '../../assets/splitImages/frame_13_delay-0.08s.jpg';
import frame14 from '../../assets/splitImages/frame_14_delay-0.08s.jpg';
import frame15 from '../../assets/splitImages/frame_15_delay-0.08s.jpg';
import frame16 from '../../assets/splitImages/frame_16_delay-0.08s.jpg';
import frame17 from '../../assets/splitImages/frame_17_delay-0.08s.jpg';
import frame18 from '../../assets/splitImages/frame_18_delay-0.08s.jpg';
import frame19 from '../../assets/splitImages/frame_19_delay-0.08s.jpg';

class ImageDisplay extends Component {
  state = {
    imageIndex: 0,
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    this.loop = setInterval(() => {
      this.setImageIndex();
    }, 1000);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.loop);
  }

  setImageIndex = () => {
    let { imageIndex } = this.state;
    if (imageIndex === 19) {
      imageIndex = 0;
    } else {
      imageIndex += 1;
    }
    this.setState({ imageIndex });
  }

  render() {
    const { imageIndex } = this.state;
    const imageList = [
      frame0,
      frame1,
      frame2,
      frame3,
      frame4,
      frame5,
      frame6,
      frame7,
      frame8,
      frame9,
      frame10,
      frame11,
      frame12,
      frame13,
      frame14,
      frame15,
      frame16,
      frame17,
      frame18,
      frame19,
    ];

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <img src={imageList[imageIndex]} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default ImageDisplay;
```